# Nodejs - Express - Nested Post data not parsing properly

Tags: node.js, express

I want to post form with nested post element

**View in HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Tag here" class="gui-input" name="reply_message">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Label for Decision" class="gui-input" name="decision[0][label]" value="Interested">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter decision keywords here" class="gui-input" data-role="tagsinput" name="decision[0][keyword]" value="Interested, call me">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Label for Decision" class="gui-input" name="decision[1][label]" value="Not Interested">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter decision keywords here" class="gui-input" data-role="tagsinput" name="decision[1][keyword]" value="not interested, not">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Label for Decision" class="gui-input" name="decision[2][label]" value="Call Later"  >
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter decision keywords here" class="gui-input" data-role="tagsinput" name="decision[2][keyword]" value="Interested, call me, later">
<button class="button btn-primary" type="submit">Submit </button>
```

**Router File**

```
router.post('/mapping', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
   var posted_data= req.body;
   console.log(req.body);
   res.send(posted_data);
});
```

**I am getting Posted Data structure like this**

```
{
    "reply_message": "This is test",
    "decision[0][label]": "Interested",
    "decision[0][keyword]": "Interested, call me",
    "decision[1][label]": "Not Interested",
    "decision[1][keyword]": "not interested, not",
    "decision[2][label]": "Call Later",
    "decision[2][keyword]": "Interested, call me, later"
}
```

But actual Posted data structure should be

```
{
    "reply_message": "This is test",
    "decision": [{
        "label": "Interested",
        "keyword": "Interested, call me"
    }, {
        "label": "Not Interested",
        "keyword": "not interested, not"
    }, {
        "label": "Call Later",
        "keyword": "Interested, call me, later"
    }]
}
```

So how ca I achieve this, Is there any node module i have to use for posted form data like this?

Comment: Are you using an old version of Express and/or `body-parser`? The default configuration for `body-parser` will automatically parse that input properly. See the [`extended` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended).

Comment: I am using latest version of both... which extended option I have to use for parsing in nested way.

Comment: The one I'm linking to, which is the default. However, since the `action` of your form is empty, I assume that you're using some sort of client-side code to submit the data? Are you sure that's being done okay? For instance, you're not submitting the data as JSON, by any chance?

Comment: I am simply post form without any correction by Javascript or jQuery

Comment: I posted a standalone version of your form, and an Express handler, [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/94a5616529dd519385baa7f8100b942a). It works just fine.

Comment: Not working unfortunately, it gives me response like <pre>{
  "reply_message": "i am very interested, but call me later",
  "decision[0][label]": "Interested",
  "decision[0][keyword]": "Interested, call me",
  "decision[1][label]": "Not Interested",
  "decision[1][keyword]": "not interested, not",
  "decision[2][label]": "Call Later",
  "decision[2][keyword]": "Interested, call me, later"
}</pre>

Comment: What does `npm ls express body-parser` return?

Comment: application@0.0.0 C:\nodejs\client-ai
├── body-parser@1.15.2
└── express@4.13.4

Comment: I'm using `express@4.14.0`, but I doubt that it's caused by that. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Crome 53.0.2785.116

Comment: In that case, I don't know why it's not working. I'm using the same browser, (almost) the same packages, and it works fine for me :(

Comment: Ok, no problem.. I am  appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `name="decision[0][label]"` is working correctly. Form Data is submitted as key-value pairs and name of input becomes the key.

If the form was submitted using HTTP GET, you would get desired object in `req.query`. However for HTTP POST, it comes in `req.body` as is.

Here, the [`qs` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) can help you on server side:

```
const qs = require('qs');

const input = {
    "reply_message": "This is test",
    "decision[0][label]": "Interested",
    "decision[0][keyword]": "Interested, call me",
    "decision[1][label]": "Not Interested",
    "decision[1][keyword]": "not interested, not",
    "decision[2][label]": "Call Later",
    "decision[2][keyword]": "Interested, call me, later"
};

const output = qs.parse(qs.stringify(input)); 

console.log(output);

// console:
{ reply_message: 'This is test',                                                                                                
  decision:                                                                                                                     
   [ { label: 'Interested', keyword: 'Interested, call me' },                                                                   
     { label: 'Not Interested', keyword: 'not interested, not' },                                                               
     { label: 'Call Later', keyword: 'Interested, call me, later' } ] }
```